# how to render a collection in rails using jquery and partials

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, collections, partial-views, render

I'm trying to render a collection of comments on Rails 3.1, but only the first comment on the collection is shown on the webpage (comments are associated to a thought).

First, the comments-controller:

```
def index
  @comments = Comment.find_by_thought_id(params[:thought_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then, the view index.js.erb

```
$("#thought_<%= params[:thought_id] %>").append("<%= escape_javascript(render'index') %>").effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
```

I'm rendering index, so now to _index.html.erb

```
<div id="comments_<%= params[:thought_id] %>">
  <%= render @comments %>
</div>
```

And finally the _comment.html.erb

```
<%= div_for comment do %>
  Posted <%=time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)%> ago<br />
  <%= link_to 'Delete', comment_path(comment), :method => :delete, :class => "delete", :remote => true  %>
  <%= content_tag(:p, comment.description, :class => "comment-body") %>
<% end %>
```

Why is Rails only giving me back one comment?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Comment.find_by_thought_id
```

try:

```
Comment.find_all_by_thought_id
```

Comment: Maybe this will teach you to use `Comment.where(thought_id: params[:thought_id])` instead of hard_to_read_and_maintain dynamic finders :)

Answer (score 0):

```
1.9.3-head :035 > Tag.find_by_name('ruby')
  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = 'ruby' LIMIT 1
 => #<Tag id: 1231, name: "ruby", created_at: "2012-04-23 10:25:07", updated_at: "2012-04-23 10:25:07"> 
1.9.3-head :036 > Tag.where(:name => 'ruby')
  Tag Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."name" = 'ruby'
 => [#<Tag id: 1231, name: "ruby", created_at: "2012-04-23 10:25:07", updated_at: "2012-04-23 10:25:07">, #<Tag id: 2420, name: "ruby", created_at: "2012-04-23 18:21:35", updated_at: "2012-04-23 18:21:35">]
```

Notice this **LIMIT 1** when you do dynamic finder like **find_by_name**.

You better use **where**, it is faster, because it is not dynamic method.